# How would you set the default wallpaper zoom type for multiple monitors?

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, settings, desktop-background

I am using two Dell 17" monitors and have them set up fine. Its just that when ever I change the wallpaper, the default setting is "zoom" but what I want is "span" because I have two monitors. Is there any way to set "span" as the default option when changing wallpapers?

Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Comment: Too bad this question was closed, an answer would have helped me.